# How to formalise: There are no geniuses but Newton was a genius

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

How would you formalise: "There are no geniuses but Newton was a genius"?

I thought it could be:
$$\neg\forall x(Px) \land Pa$$
and also $$\neg\exists x (Px) \land Pa$$These both seem to make sense and formalise the sentence, however they are not identical statements. The way it is worded is really confusing!

Comment: Are you using ``are`` and ``was`` synonymously? I could interpret it as, there ``are`` no geniuses **now**, but there **were** geniuses at some point.

Comment: Yes I think it is meant to be synonymous... that was all the information I was give. Sorry, didn't make it clear that Px: x is/was a genius; a: a is/was Newton

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The second one looks right to me. If by $Px$ you mean "$x$ is a genius" and $a$ is Newton, then your statements translate to:

1) it's not true that every person is a genius, and it's true that Newton is a genius;

2) there's doesn't exist anyone who is a genius, and it's true that Newton is a genius

Comment: Thanks, so that means $\forall x (\neg Px)\land Pa$ is the same as (2)... intuitively it feels strange! Thanks for the help.

Comment: "No one is a genius" doesn't intuitively feel the same as "everybody is not a genius" to you? Don't worry, you'll get used to it :) Remember that you can accept an answer if your doubts have been cleared

Answer (score 7):

One way to formalize this would be $\bot$, since that statement is a contradiction ... Unless of course the point of the sentence is that there are no geniuses *now*, though we have had geniuses in the past, like Newton.

One way to formalize that would be to use a predicate $G(x,t)$ which says that $x$ is a genius at time $t$. So then:

$\neg \exists x G(x,t_{now}) \land \exists t (t<t_{now} \land G(newton,t))$

Comment: Might want to add something like $... \land t < t_{now}$ (for "was" rather than "will be") :-)

Comment: @psmears yeah, good catch, thanks!

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! The question was in the worksheet that did not want us to use dyadic predicates, but it's definitely much more accurate!